# How to get foreign key name of loaded relationship using laravel eloquent

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

So I currently have 3 models `Specie` `Type` `User`. I want to be able to get the name of the last modified user in relation to the `Specie` model

The relationships are as follows

```
Class Specie extends Model {
   public function type()
   {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Type', 'type_id');
   }

   public function user()
   {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'user_id');
   }
}

Class Type extends Model {
   public function specie()
   {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Specie', 'type_id');
   }
}

Class User extends Model {
   public function specie()
   {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Specie', 'user_id');
   }
}
```

I have tried this

```
Class Specie extends Model {
    public function lastModified()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'last_modified_by');
    }
}
```

And then used the below code

```
$this->type->with(['specie.lastModified' => function ($query) use 
        ($userId) {
            $query->where('user_id', $userId);
        }])->get();
```

Unfortunately this does not seem to work

However, by using this code

```
$this->type->with(['specie' => function ($query) use ($userId) {
            $query->where('user_id', $userId);
        }])->get();
```

I am able to get this:

```
"id": 1,
"type": "Halo",
"created_at": "2019-07-20 13:02:53",
"updated_at": "2019-07-20 13:02:53",
"specie": [
  {
    "id": 5,
    "user_id": 1,
    "type_id": 1,
    "note": "et",
    "created_by": 1,
    "last_modified_by": 1,
  }
]
```

However, what I want to get is the name of the last modified person name which is the primary key in the `User` model and the foreign key in the `Specie` model

This is what I expect to get:

```
"id": 1,
"type": "Halo",
"created_at": "2019-07-20 13:02:53",
"updated_at": "2019-07-20 13:02:53",
"specie": [
  {
    "id": 5,
    "user_id": 1,
    "type_id": 1,
    "note": "et",
    "created_by": 1,
    "last_modified_by": 1,
    "last_modified_name": 'gerrard'
  }
]
```

Comment: you have no any model of  lastModified ??

Comment: LastModified is not a model

Comment: so first of all create this model and in model define your table name..ok

Comment: There is no table lastModified...
The Specie table has 2 foreign keys `user_id` and `last_modified_by`
The value of the last_modified_by is the user id from the user model...
The user model has a name, so I want to get the name of that user..
Please read the question again

Answer (score 1):

From your Eloquent entity relationships:

`Specie` and `Type(type)` are related (one-to-many)

`Specie` and `User(user)` are related (one-to-many)

`Specie` and `User(lastModified)` are related (one-to-many)

`User` and `Type` are **not** related

So, for you to include the user name you have to query the `Specie` model through the `lastModified()` method.

```php
$this->lastModified()->with(['specie' => function ($query) use ($userId) {
            $query->where('user_id', $userId);
        }])->get();
```

You should expect a result like this

```php
"id": 1,
"name": "the_user_name" 
// any other user data
"created_at": "2019-07-20 13:02:53",
"updated_at": "2019-07-20 13:02:53",
"specie": [
  {
    "id": 5,
    "user_id": 1,
    "type_id": 1,
    "note": "et",
    "created_by": 1,
    "last_modified_by": 1,
  }
]
```

From the result, the field(foreign key) `last_modified_by` in `specie` with value `1` should match the field `id` in `user`.

Also, I'm assuming the field for your user name is `name`. It would be included with the returned user data.

**UPDATE**

You can **not** get any user data from the `User` table through the `Type` table using eager loading except they are related. Ergo, models must be related (i.e. constrained by each other) before they can be nested, for instance using eager loading. See this [medium article](https://medium.com/@sander3/laravel-nested-eager-loading-contraints-9742c2dac4b9) to better understand this.

Comment: Did you include the `lastModified()` method in the`Specie` model? Also, from where are you using the query `$this->...`?

Comment: This is not the rest I expect, can you please check the expected result in my question?

Comment: If you are not getting your expected result then `"last_modified_name"` is **not** a field in your `Specie` table. Is it?

Comment: It is a field in the User table

Comment: I need to get the type name as the main object and not the user. I want the user to be part of the specie array

Comment: There lies your answer. You must query the `user` table to get the user name. Also, having `last_modified_by` and `last_modified_name` in one table (or query result) is redundant. If you have `last_modified_by`, then you can get the name from the user table.

Comment: Yes, but i want to do a nested eager load. I must use the type to get the desired result. Can't I do nested eager loading?

Comment: Yes you can. But, the `Type` model and `User` model must be related first. From your models, they aren't.

Answer (score 0):

I used the `getKeyName()` method on the related model.

My relationship was a one to many so returned as a `Collection`.
Accessing the returned collections first item in collection [0] and then running the `getKeyName()` worked.

Below my code first checks if the relation data is filled and that its returned as a Collection (multiple) and that there is atleast 1 item.

```
if(
$item->relatives 
&& $item->relatives instanceof \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection 
&& count($item->relatives)
) {

     $relation_key = $item->relatives[0]->getKeyName();
}
```

I presume you could test if relation is return as a Collection of Models or a single Model is returned.

If a single model is returned you can just:
`$item->relative->getKeyName();`